How to Prevent Glitching in bar_chart_race Animation with Dynamic x-Axis Scaling (fixed_max=False)
I'm creating a bar chart race video using the bar_chart_race package in Python, but I'm encountering an issue when toggling the fixed_max setting. When fixed_max is set to True, the video looks smooth and stable. However, setting it to False introduces glitches, especially when large values (like 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000) are added on the x-axis. I’d like to better understand why this is happening and how to make the data visualization more effective when fixed_max=False.
I tried setting fixed_max to False to let the x-axis dynamically adjust to the data range, expecting a smoother scaling effect. However, this change resulted in glitches during playback. I expected the bar chart to handle the dynamically changing x-axis limits smoothly, but instead, it disrupts the animation. I’d appreciate any suggestions to resolve this or improve data visualization.
Here’s the relevant code:
import bar_chart_race as bcr
import pandas as pd
import warnings
from datetime import datetime

# Get the current time and format it
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")

# Ignore all warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

df = pd.read_csv("raw_data.csv", index_col="Date",parse_dates=["Date"], dayfirst=True)

# replace empty values with 0
df.fillna(0.0, inplace=True)

# Apply a moving average with a window size adjust as needed
df_smooth = df.rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).mean()

# Define the output filename
filename = f'YouTube Subscriber Growth {current_time}.mp4'

# using the bar_chart_race package
bcr.bar_chart_race(
    # must be a DataFrame where each row represents a single period of time.
    df=df_smooth,

    # name of the video file
    filename=filename,

    # specify location of image folder
    img_label_folder="YT Channel Images",

    # change the Figure properties
    fig_kwargs={
        'figsize': (26, 15),
        'dpi': 120,
        'facecolor': '#D3D3D3'
    },

    # orientation of the bar: h or v
    orientation="h",

    # sort the bar for each period
    sort="desc",

    # number of bars to display in each frame
    n_bars=5,

    # If set to True, this smoothens the transition between periods by interpolating values
    # during each frame, making the animation smoother. This is useful when there are significant
    # changes in data between periods, and it ensures that the bars move more fluidly.
    interpolate_period=True,

    # to fix the maximum value of the axis
    fixed_max=False,

    # smoothness of the animation
    steps_per_period=90,

    # time period in ms for each row
    period_length=1500,

    # custom set of colors
    colors=[
           '#FF4500', '#DC143C', '#F08080', '#FF6347',
    '#00BFFF', '#1E90FF', '#7B68EE', '#00FFFF',
    '#00FA9A', '#7CFC00', '#32CD32', '#2E8B57',
    '#FFD700', '#FAFAD2', '#FFFACD', '#F0E68C',
    '#EE82EE', '#BA55D3', '#8A2BE2', '#663399'],

    # title and its styles
    title={'label': 'YouTube Subscriber Growth',
           'size': 52,
           'weight': 'bold',
           'pad': 40
           },

    # adjust the position and style of the period label
    period_label={'x': .95, 'y': .15,
                  'ha': 'right',
                  'va': 'center',
                  'size': 72,
                  'weight': 'semibold'
                  },

    # style the bar label text
    bar_label_font={'size': 27},

    # style the labels in x and y axis
    tick_label_font={'size': 27},

    # adjust the style of bar
    # alpha is opacity of bar
    # ls - width of edge
    bar_kwargs={'alpha': .99, 'lw': 0},

    # adjust the bar label format
    bar_texttemplate='{x:.0f}',

    # adjust the period label format
    period_template='%B %d, %Y',
)
print("Chart creation completed. Video saved as", filename, sep=' ',end='.')

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mxfWe4E0c2TYcU3DYdmHz1Z2CShe9017/view?usp=drive_link
Data Input(raw_data.csv):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gVc9_zI0CgWIeZ3-VV33nWyGnCaIA3jb/view?usp=drive_link
Output Videos:
With fixed_max:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L1BnqYCZU_vPt1SYegftvCr_BmhkzDW1/view?usp=drive_link
Without fixed_max:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dPa18P4klVwgnshNMkvqHktoibPg3OfI/view?usp=drive_link
